# How to make scrollable with stack Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm unable to use `SingleChildScrollView` for scrolling it with stack widget,

[image]

I Used `Positioned()` , and `Column()`  widget and with stack

`Positioned()` used for cancel, menu, logout widgets, 
and `Column()` used for GAIN OF THE DAY , PROFILE, & CONTACT US button.

CODE:

```
 body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 20.0,
            left: 10.0,
            child: // cancel icon
          ),
         Positioned(
            top: 60.0,
            child: //MENU WIDGET
          ),
         Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[  
             Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                 GestureDetector(
                      //GAIN OF THE DAY ICON BUTTON
                    ),
                 GestureDetector(
                     //PROFILE PAGE BUTTON
                    )
                ],
              ),
               GestureDetector(
                //CONTACT US BUTTON
               ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
          // LOG OUT WIDGET
          ),

        ],
      ),
```

Comment: What is the question?:

Comment: Please Make it scrollable.
My LogOut widget is not visible properly.

Comment: I removed . I placed it as the parent widget of  Coulmn().